# Magento 2: How do I create widget with dynamic fields?

Tags: widget, magento2, custom-field-type

Example of widget's dynamic fields:

[image: Example of widget's dynamic fields]

Please help!

Comment: You mean you want to create this in the administration config?

Comment: No. I mean Cms Widget

Comment: @valir DId you find any solutions fro it?